# Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: UIAElementNil is not a function (evaluating 'tableView.cells().logElementTree()')

Tags: uitableview, instruments, ui-automation, uiatableview

This line of UI Automation code:

```
tableView.logElementTree();
```

gives this:

[image]

but then doing this

```
tableView.cells().logElementTree();
```

gives me this:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: UIAElementNil is not a function (evaluating 'tableView.cells().logElementTree()')
```

This worked for another tableView I was working with so what's the difference here? And any suggestions on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.cells()` returns an array of table cells. You will need to pick a cell that you would like to print the log tree of either by name `tableView.cells()["cellName"]` or by index, `tableView.cells()[0]`. Or if you want to see the log tree of each cell you can print it in a loop.